# java.net.UnknownHostException - Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

[image]I am getting `java.net.UnknownHostException`when trying to execute below code. Is there some proxy settings i need to change?

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();
String title = doc.title();
System.out.println(title);
```

Error trace below

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: example.com
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:512)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)
at Start.main(Start.java:28)
```

Comment: OK, ignore my previous comment, I was wrong, this site exist. But I can't reproduce your problem since your code generates `Example Domain` for me.

Comment: well, then looks to me it is some kind of firewall issue. Will investigate in that direction.

Comment: Can you access that site from the browser? You could also try pinging it from the command line to see what happens

Comment: yes i can open the site from browser but unable to ping. please find attached pic

Comment: Apologies!!! just disconnected from VPN and now all working fine.

Comment: Please provide the solution as an answer and accept that. It will be valuable to other users as well.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and I discovered later I had slow internet connection

Answer (score 0):

Apologies!!! just disconnected from VPN and now all working fine.